# Imported C-function works in C# but not in VB6

Tags: c#, c, dll, vb6

I'm working on a problem for a few days now and can't seem to find the answer. I have a third party dll written in C, which i have to use in an VB6 application.

The function inside dll looks something like this:

```
someFunction(WContext* context, const unsigned char* seed, int seedLength, const unsigned char* name, int nameLength, 
             const unsigned char* pin, int pinLength, const char* description)
```

I have an example written in c#. I tried it out and it works just fine. This is what it looks like in C#

```
[DllImport("Filename.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int someFunction(IntPtr context, byte[] seed, int seedLength, byte[] name, int nameLength, 
                                       byte[] pin, int pinLength, string description)
```

This is later used in the example like this:

```
byte[] seed = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("seed")
byte[] name = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("name")
byte[] pin = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1234")
string description = "description"

int result = someFunction(context, seed, seed.length, name, name.Length, pin, pin.Length, description)
```

Now this works just fine in C#. I get 0 as a result which means in that case that the operation was a success.
I want to make this work in VB6. I tried it with some other functions of the dll and they work just like they should. This one gives me a headache. Here is what I tried just like with any other function:

First I imported the function into my code so I could use it later. I did this with a few other functions the same way and it worked fine.

```
Private Declare Function someFunction Lib "C:\DllPath\Filename.dll" (ByVal context As Long, ByRef seed as Byte, _
                                                                     ByVal seedLength As Integer, ByRef name As Byte, _
                                                                     ByVal nameLength As Integer, ByRef pin As Byte, _
                                                                     ByVal pinLength As Integer, ByVal description As String) As Integer
```

Next Step was for me to call the function. I did it this way:
(I do get the context from another function earlier so this already has a value. Other functions work fine with that variable)

```
Dim seed() As Byte
Dim seedLength As Integer
Dim name() As Byte
Dim nameLength As Integer
Dim pin() As Byte
Dim pin As Integer
Dim description As String
Dim result as Integer

seed = StrConv("seed", vbFromUnicode)
seedLength = UBound(seed) + 1
name = StrConv("name", vbFromUnicode)
nameLength = UBound(name) + 1
pin = StrConv("1234", vbFromUnicode)
pinLength = UBound(pin) + 1
description = "description"

result = someFunction(context, seed(0), seedLength, name(0), nameLength, pin(0), pinLength, description)
```

The value for result is 1. By the documentation I got this means invalid parameter. Now I researched a lot. Read that in VB6 I have to give the first element of the byte array just like I did in my code. Tried it first with the whole array, got the same result. I think it has something to do with the arrays since its the first function that I've taken over to my code that had those. I'm also not really that native with VB6 but I have to do this. Maybe some of you guys know why this doesn't work. Probably just a minor mistake by myself.

Comment: I cannot give specific help for VB, but to debug this you could create your own DLL that contains a function with a similar signature that prints its arguments to show what it received from your VB program.

Comment: VB6 is not managed while c# is managed.  See : http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869371-Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-VB6

Comment: VB6 does not support the "cdecl" calling convention. It only supports the "stdcall" calling convention. Your third party DLL seems to be using "cdecl" calling convention, so its functions cannot be called directly from VB6.

Comment: @IanAbbott i have different versions of that DLL. One of them uses stdcall which I'm using in my code. All functions do work at this point but not this one.

Comment: First thing I notice is that your data type translation for C+ ìnt` is wrong. `int` in C+ is a signed 32-bit integer, which translates to `Long` in VB6.

Answer (score 2):

In VB6 it's as simple as this

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function someFunction Lib "C:\DllPath\Filename.dll" (ByVal context As Long, ByVal seed As String, _
                                                                     ByVal seedLength As Long, ByVal name As String, _
                                                                     ByVal nameLength As Long, ByVal pin As String, _
                                                                     ByVal pinLength As Long, ByVal description As String) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim context     As Long
    Dim seed        As String
    Dim name        As String
    Dim pin         As String
    Dim description As String
    Dim result      As Long

    seed = "seed"
    name = "name"
    pin = "1234"
    description = "description"
    result = someFunction(context, seed, Len(seed), name, Len(name), pin, Len(pin), description)
End Sub
```

Just don't use `Integer` at all (only `Long`s) use `ByVal ... As String` for the runtime to do the Unicode->ANSI conversion and be done with it.

The original API is weirdly declared with `unsigned char *` pointer and separate `int` length parameter probably because the `seed`, `name` and `pin` strings can contain `\0` embedded while `description` is plain zero-terminated string which explains the PITA w/ the C/C++ prototype.

VB6 strings are length-prefixed (**and** zero-terminated) from get go and **can** contain `Chr$(0)` by design so there is no need to take any additional measures like in `C#` sample w/ explicit `byte[]` arrays conversion and function prototype signature fiddling. Just use `ByVal ... As String` in the API declare.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Tried it and I'm getting a different error now that is not documented in the API documentation. It's a start. Thank you.

Comment: Found the error. I kept the byte arrays in the function and didn't use strings. I don't know why but it's good now.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a declared API, VB6 will convert a String to an ANSI byte array automatically, so you can declare seed, name, and pin as ByVal Strings.

Description is a bit confusion to me though, since I don't see a length being passed for that one.  Is this really a null-terminated string (pszDescription)?  How does the API you are calling know how long this character buffer is?

Comment: That confused me as well but thats what the documentation says. I tried it with strings, still doesnt work but thanks for the help anyway.
Can't seem to find a solution. I tried something now. Created a dll in VB to call those functions from the C dll. Added that new VB dll to my VB6 program and now it works like a charm. Don't know if this is a good way to do it but it works for now.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to change the function declaration in VB, making seed, name, and pin ByRef As Byte(),

note the parentheses:

```
Private Declare Function someFunction Lib "C:\DllPath\Filename.dll" (ByVal context As Long, ByRef seed as Byte(), _
                                                                 ByVal seedLength As Integer, ByRef name As Byte(), _
                                                                 ByVal nameLength As Integer, ByRef pin As Byte(), _
                                                                 ByVal pinLength As Integer, ByVal description As String) As Integer
```

Then, when calling the function, pass the entire arrays, not the first elements:

```
result = someFunction(context, seed, seedLength, name, nameLength, pin, pinLength, description)
```

Comment: Thank you, gave it a try but i get the same result.